# How do I search a field for a substring?

Tags: python, string, search, substring

```
   Number1     Number2     Info1
1) 19124451932~18374913342~0- 9124441932
2) 18436889349~17064219321~0- 2024281123
3) 13352808654~19703842247~0- 9703842247
```

I'm looking for an `if-clause` which evaluates `True` when the last 9 digits of `Info1` are a substring of `Number1` and/or `Number2` for that row.

This would be part of a larger If condition in python. I can find plenty of ways to search a substring for a full string, but I can't find anything about searching a full string for a substring based on character length.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

This ought to be reasonably easy. Assuming the lines look just like you have written, you can do something like this:

```
number1, number2, info1 = (s.strip() for s in line.split('~'))
if any(info1[-9:] in n for n in (number1, number2)):
    pass # Do stuff
```

This works as follows:

- First, split your line into the three relevant parts, and assign them to your variable names.
- Then, for each of `(number1, number2)`, see if the substring composed of the final nine characters of `info1` are present. If they are, your conditions have been met.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
import re
with open("abc") as f:
    next(f)   #skip header
    for line in f:
        n1,n2 = re.findall("(\w+)~",line)
        info = line.split()[-1]
        if info[-9:] in n1 or info[-9:] in n2:
            print "yes"
        else:
            print "no"
```

**output:**

```
no
no
yes
```